# Sorting out largest values in a column with unique names

Tags: excel

I have a column, `A`

```
6
2
6
2
21
18
```

I have another column, `B`. This column extracts the largest values from column `A`.

```
21
18
6
6
2
2
```

I have a third column, `C`

```
Rob
Jerome
Pete
Alistair
Gunther
Alpha
```

The individuals in `C` have values from `A` associated with them

I have a final column, `D`, where individuals are placed as such

```
Jerome 21
Alistair 18
Rob 6
Rob 6
Alpha 2
Alpha 2
```

I want column D to display each unique individual as such:

```
Jerome 21
Alistair 18
Rob 6
Pete 6
Alpha 2
Gunther 2
```

How do I go from what I HAVE in column `D`, to what I WANT in column `D`?

My code:

```
=INDEX(A2:A250,MATCH(LARGE(AM$2:AM$250,ROWS(AP$2:AP2)),AM2:AM250,0),)&" : "&LARGE(AM$2:AM$250,ROWS(AP$2:AP2))& " times "
```

Comment: Data -> Data Tools -> Remove Duplicates ?

Comment: Unfortunately, my luck is not good. so something simple like that didnt work There  is no change in the column info

Comment: seems to me the names are not correct if they are supposed to line up with Column As numbers, wouldn't Gunther be 21 and so on?

Comment: I see what you mean. These columns are just fake representations of data I actually have, but I was trying to give you a simple example on what that data looks like and what I want it to look like. On my actual file, the numbers DO line with their names exactly as you noticed.

Comment: Seems to me that if `Remove Duplicates` doesn't change anything, then **all** of the entries are Unique.  Or maybe your "fake representation" is so fake that it doesn't represent your real data, in which case it is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

As stated expected output does not match your verbiage, so I took a swing.

In D1 put:

```
=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($C$1:$C$6)/($A$1:$A$6=B1),COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B1)))& " " &B1
```

and copy down.

[image]

---

And just because I can.  This formula will remove the need for the helper column B:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$1:$B$6)/($A$1:$A$6=LARGE($A$1:$A$6,ROW(A1))),SUMPRODUCT(--(LARGE($A$1:$A$6,ROW($ZY$1:INDEX($ZY:$ZY,ROW(A1))))=LARGE($A$1:$A$6,ROW(A1))))))& " " &LARGE($A$1:$A$6,ROW(A1))
```

[image]